# Copying a same-key property error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

What is the correct way in TypeScript to copy properties from source to destination, using the same key-type?

```
interface ITest {
    first?(val: number, msg: string): void;
    second?(): void
}

function copy(e: keyof ITest, source: ITest, dest: ITest) {
    // TS2322:
    // Type '(val: number, msg: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
    dest[e] = source[e];
}
```

I can't understand why TypeScript fails to see that source and destination are the same type and that we use the same key-type. But how else are we supposed to do it then?

---

I'm using TypeScript 3.6.4, with `tsconfig.json` as below:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es6",
  "strict": true
 }
```

Comment: Is this purely out of interest as I am assuming you wouldn't actually do this in a real application? It probably has something to do with 'e' being a subtype of string but is like a list of strings which would be all the keys of the object

Comment: @Magrangs I cannot fathom what would make you think that. This is a 100% real-world example. I have an interface with about 10+ callbacks that I need set from a source and then changed to previous values. And so I need those type of operations in a few places.

Comment: Why would you bother though? Just pass in a string which is the key you want to copy. Why over complicate it?

Comment: @Magrangs I can't. I simplified the example here, but in my case the copy involves a number of verifications and scenarios. I do not want to take a large piece of code and then repeat it separately for every function I have in the interface. It looks horrendous that way.

Comment: Sorry, obviously the problem of copying properties is a common one, I was referring to the use of keyof. Can't you just use string instead of keyof e (as the type for the param). The outcome is the same and it's only a compile time 'thing' anyway.

Comment: Just seems overly complicated, under the hood it's a string anyway, just use a string for the type of the param. You are using square bracket notation for object property access which takes a string anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS3.5 introduced a [change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) to enforce more type safety when writing to properties whose key is a union.  In terms of just the *types*, the compiler can't tell the difference between what you're trying to do, and the definitely unsafe code here:

```
function badCopy(k1: keyof ITest, k2: keyof ITest, o: ITest) {
  o[k2] = o[k1]; // error!
}
```

Here, the key `k1` and `k2` are exactly the same type: `keyof ITest`.  But there's a good chance you're trying to blindly copy a property from one key to an incompatible property at another key.  Because the key *values* in `k1` and `k2` might not be the same, despite being the same type.  That's unsafe, so you get an error.

---

Unfortunately that change also causes what you're doing to get deemed as "possibly unsafe" even though you know for sure that `e` is the same exact value in both the read and the write.  This is currently considered a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31445) in TypeScript, although it's possible that they might consider [special-casing identical key identifiers](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693#issuecomment-518311469).  If you care about that, you might want to go to the related GitHub issue (it looks like [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693) is still listed as "in discussion") and give it a  or describe your use case if it's more compelling than what's listed there.

---

That being said there are workarounds until and unless that gets resolved:

The compiler still allows the [loophole](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) where an *identical* type is assignable to itself, as long as the compiler can't see that you are using a union-type as your key type.  Often you can make your functions more [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), like this:

```
function copy<K extends keyof ITest>(e: K, source: ITest, dest: ITest) {  
  dest[e] = source[e]; // no error now
}
```

Or, if you don't want to do that, just accept that you know better than the compiler here and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it not to worry:

```
function copyAssert(e: keyof ITest, source: ITest, dest: ITest) {
  dest[e] = source[e] as any; // one way
  dest[e] = source[e] as ITest["first"] & ITest["second"]; // more explicit 
}
```

Hopefully one of those works for you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyyMwUOA-ABQBucANgFzIgCuAtgEbQA0y7WAObMcUUIICUzGgHtgAEwDcRZFggIZIedSnJZCggF8CBGKxAIwwTck5x5AYRkAHAJ5UA1gEZmHiK5kYNEwcPg8AJl9-QODsMD4ZZgw4iXwVGQBtCIBdZABeZEzvbMVkAHoy5GgoGSgjE1NzS2sQZA03AHEIEGhgBAAeAGkqgA9ILSxkPwCg5JwAPioIZkG+LBlWKCQkkPjkeTidlLTiA5wMiFyC9c2kC5L6xosrG3bXAEEsNSgwJaiZ2KhVQbLbLQF7M5gI44VKEU5xe75YG3CCIuCTOAgVylCqFHrIADucFcKkhiOuILul2Q6PBGQARKRyGB6bkAGR0+lqDRaVk4yrsWooCAjZz0PrAXBGIA)

Comment: Brilliant answer, and right to the point. You are being very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the signatures of your two properties:

```
(val: number, msg: string) => void
```

and

```
() => void
```

The error you are getting looks like the compiler is saying you are assigning across keys. The problem is they're both functions but with different signatures. Your type for e is a union of those two signatures:

```
e: "first" | "second"
```

If Typescript supported reified types this would be easy but for now [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=3&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgKhAzsKBeWAxAlgJ2VAMlgGUIBjAewDsATAKDqyuAhwDMBDM6GbPFCAA8WtRLDjhoAbyh0o8qKEgAuKAHI2uZGrkLN-APwAKAG4cANqqoBXALYAjVgBootxAHNVyHE3cBKVRMKLBoAbjoAXwZGZlZObhJyahooIREaMXhJKBldeSUIVTVEJNodBSgSylpjAKggkMiGJhZ2Lh4JSBzZCoKi-W0oAB91KuSdKIY2ayoyYCxqKEowECNC8UkXRAprHG5VeCRgFxojg4RkPxy8yoB3LGAyAAsoNYA6AqupG4qyDhL1ANgGplD8KgpqvggWhUlB-pgtMAweCoKdkABtIEfSQAXRh2123ExiOxkBx4RRKPsOAgHAA1hTKX8AcVSjQQcjwZCUGNaDDoPCYKRqvRKeC0cB0byaKSIHj0AS9hApWzZeTORVqbSGTcohEgA) is the best I can do. Essentially pulling Typescripts type info kicking and screaming into the Runtime environment.

```
type ITest = IFirst & ISecond

interface IFirst extends IType { 
    type: 'first'
    first?(val: number, msg: string): void;
}

interface ISecond extends IType { 
    type: 'second'
    second?(): void
}

interface IType { 
    type: 'first' | 'second'
}

function copy(e: IType, source: ITest, dest: ITest) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'first':
            const first = e as IFirst
            dest[first.type] = source[first.type];
            break;
        case 'second':
            const second = e as ISecond
            dest[second.type] = source[second.type];
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why TypeScript fails to see that source and destination are the same type and that we use the same key-type.

I don't truly know if this case can't be solved by TypeScript, but what I know is that TypeScript's compiler (or any other language under certain constraints) [can't check every possible truth](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833) (in this case, that those elements are equal). This seems to be your case.

> But how else are we supposed to do it then?

Sometimes, humans need to give hints to the compiler. In this case, I'd use `any` to stop the compiler to report errors.